# Patch and Paint a Desk Surface

Tags: repair, paint, desk

I'd like to patch the chip in this desk surface and paint the entire surface. The chip is on the back, so I can afford it not being perfect, just something to level out that wont be noticeable under fresh paint.

Can someone give me advice on fixing the chip, and what paint would be best for this type of project? It will be primarily a computer desk with minimal abuse, not a workbench.

[image: Desk Surface Chip]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a high-performance 2-part wood filler (it's kinda like auto body filler). *Over*fill the area then shave it down with a Surform plane (a cheesegrater plane), then use coarse, medium, and fine sandpaper to smooth.

That desk could present problems regarding paint, the surface (it looks like a shiny laminate) is designed for stuff **not** to stick to it. I would fine sand the top, paint it with a "difficult surface" primer like BIN, then finish off with a high quality gloss paint. If you use lame brushes, your paint job will be lame so do the opposite of that.

Comment: Agreed, though you could skip the surform step if you sliced the bondo (or surrogate) almost flush with a long sharp blade at exactly the point where the bondo has set but isn't too hard to cut. I'd describe it as medium stiff rubbery. Sadly, I can't tell you an actual time to that point, as mixes vary widely.

Comment: Someone had suggested wood filler before I posted here, sounds like the way to go. Would something like wood veneer sheets be easier to get down and stay down than paint? I prefer that look to paint but thought paint would simple.

Comment: Gluing a veneer sheet would probably give you a more durable and aesthetically pleasing surface. However it has it's own complications: difficult to cut exactly right; exposed edge that will be difficult to cover; messy gluing process, etc. I would patch and paint or buy a new desk. That one is particle board and laminate... not expensive to replace if you consider time, energy, and effort.